# Use delegated permissions on a daemon using Microsoft Graph

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph API through the OAUTH2 Authentication however I'm struggling to work out how to use Delegated Permissions and not require a user to login.

I'm happy to authenticate the app with myself once, but this will be running on a daemon/service and won't be interacted with via a user. Because of this I can't use the way Microsoft describes Delegated Permissions as that uses `/authorize` first and then a call can be made to `/token`.

I know you can use secret keys for `/token` but it seems that only is using the Application Permissions and not Delegated - which is what I have access to.

Is there a way to authenticate using Delegated Permissions as if I was a user but without a user having to use a sign in page every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. The term "delegated" is very intentional here in that it means "the user has delegated their permissions to your application so you can operate on behalf of *that* user". Application permissions are not delegated because there is no `user` in context to delegate their access rights to you.

- [Authorization Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) = Delegated Permission Scopes
- [Implicit Grants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit) == Delegated Permission Scopes
- [Client Credential Grants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) == Delegated Permission Scopes

Much of the Microsoft Graph functionality works with both Application and Delegated scopes so in many cases you can still execute the same scenarios. There are some caveats such as using the shorthand `/me` which doesn't exist when there isn't a user authenticated (instead you need to use `/users[{id}]`). There are however some cases where there isn't an equivalent Application scope and these are regularly looked at in an effort to close the gap.

Comment: So since Application Permissions require admin approval and grant access to All items (not perfect for a large AD), if I have set delegated permissions to an application but still use the API token method would I be able to use the /users[{id}] but just for things my user has permission to?

Comment: If you have requested a Delegated Permission that requires Admin Consent (i.e. `User.Read.All`) and you've received that Consent from an Admin, then yes. Once a `user` goes through OAUTH they would have permission to execute both calls to `/me` and `/users{someone-other-than me` endpoints. They still cannot execute functions that they otherwise wouldn't (i.e. if the `user` can't edit other `users` normally than your app wouldn't be able to either).

Comment: And there is no way to not use the admin only All application permissions without a user logging in via a UI for the application?

Comment: You cannot use the Delegated Permissions without a User but most of the `All` scopes have Application equivalents. For example, there is a Delegated `User.Read.All` **and** an Application `User.Read.All` scope. There are some exceptions for _very_ risky scopes; `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` for example is _only_ available to an Admin using Delegated scopes.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do something similar in a daemon app, but application permissions weren't available for the resource to which I needed access (Planner).  I was able to accomplish it using the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow and supplying credentials for a service account instead of an actual user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc