# MS Graph API Teams: Application access to Channel Messages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am looking at [Teams Channel Create Chat Message method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-chatthreads) (currently only available in beta).

We have an application which manages groups of users and would like to integrate with MS Teams - create a Team, add Channels and send messages to the channel - all without a user.  For this I have followed "[Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)".

However I notice that for this and other message level functions (list messages) Application permission is "Not Supported" and for our use case Delegated permissions is not really an option (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985275/1265200)).

**Does anyone know why these are only available for Delegated Permission? is there a plan to enable this or is will this always not be "Not supported" for Application Access?**

I appreciate that giving an Application full access to all messages may be something that Admins would not be keen on, but being able to post and retrieve messages from channels the application has created seems (to me) to be reasonable (perhaps the permissions model isn't that fine grained yet).

This is possibly an overlap of [Unable to “List channel messages” on Azure AD Graph API Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023889/1265200) - the OPs answer contains an unanswered similar question.

Answer (score 2):

We aren't currently sharing road map externally of when these types of things are being updated.

What we do ask is that you request these on our UserVoice channel so that we can track the demand and prioritize accordingly. If you can go here and add this request I'd appreciate this and I'll let the PM who owns this know https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support

Comment: Thanks - I have found a similar request in there and voted, plus left a comment < https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36117961-allow-posting-messages-to-teams-with-azure-app-rat>